# Flex DataGrid mouseover row with gradient background

Tags: apache-flex, datagrid, mouseover, gradient

I have a DataGrid that needs to show a gradient background on mouseover of the row.  I have created itemrenderers for each of the columns and the gradient shows up for the individual cell that is moused over, but not for the whole row.  How do I get the whole row to show the gradient when mousing over one of the cells?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have subclass the `DataGrid` and delve into the `ListBase` and override the `protected function drawRowHighlightIndicator()`. You'll be using the graphics class to draw what you need, so bone up on how to do that.

Comment: you lead me on the right track, but the function that needs overriding is drawHighlightIndicator

Comment: I have drawRowBackgrounds on the brain because I've been doing so much of that lately. Brain cramp. But you're right, for your purposes it's drawHighlightIndicator.